# Revit to Unity 3D Models and Texture export

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, textures, revit-api, fbx

I developed a 3D House Building in Revit. When I export the .fbx file from Revit and import it to unity, there are no textures and materials. Is there any way to export the 3D file in Revit along with textures and materials?

I also tried to import Revit to 3ds Max, and texture appears. Then I exported the house .fbx file in 3dx max and imported it to unity. When I gave extract materials, I extracts one "Generic Material" with no textures, which applies to the whole house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you export fbx to Unity from any 3D modeling software, you get your model, mesh, rigging, etc. You also get all the materials you have asigned in your modeling software, but those materials are all viewed as Unity default materials. You have to import textures you have used into unity and make materials with those textures and use them on model you have imported.

Comment: The FBX format supports embedded textures though